# How do you check for unitless variables with multiple values SASS

Tags: css, sass

I try to create a flexible mixin where you can set the space for padding or margin from the same mixin

I based it on a bourbon for positioning

```
mixin setSpace($setSpace: padding, $setSpaceValues: 0 0 0 0){
  @if type-of($setSpace) == list{
       $setSpaceValues :$setSpace;
      $setSpace: padding;
      }
        $top: nth($setSpaceValues, 1);
        $right: nth($setSpaceValues, 2);
        $bottom: nth($setSpaceValues, 3);
        $left: nth($setSpaceValues, 4);

        @if  unitless($top and $right and $bottom and $left){

        #{$setSpace}:  $top+px $right+px $bottom+px $left+px ;

       }
}
```

But I try to get the flexibility to be able to add individual units to it as well  so that I can do also

```
.test{
   @include setSpace(margin, 10% 0 5 5);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Sass [**`if()` function**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#if-instance_method) on each value to check for `unitless` ... maybe make define a function that does this - something in this direction perhaps:

```
@function setUnit($val){
  @return if(unitless($val), $val * 1px, $val);
}
```

And then you can use it in your mixin:

```
@mixin setSpace($setSpace: padding, $setSpaceValues: 0 0 0 0){
  @if type-of($setSpace) == list{
    $setSpaceValues: $setSpace;
    $setSpace: padding;
  }

  $top: nth($setSpaceValues, 1);
  $right: nth($setSpaceValues, 2);
  $bottom: nth($setSpaceValues, 3);
  $left: nth($setSpaceValues, 4);

  #{$setSpace}:  setUnit($top) setUnit($right) setUnit($bottom) setUnit($left) ;
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7596238)

in addition you could also just set the values in a loop ( - a bit more flexible and shorter):

```
@mixin setSpace($setSpace: padding, $setSpaceValues: 0 0 0 0){
  @if type-of($setSpace) == list{
    $setSpaceValues: $setSpace;
    $setSpace: padding;
  }
  $out: ();
  @each $val in $setSpaceValues{
    $out: append($out, if(unitless($val), $val * 1px, $val));
  }
  #{$setSpace}: $out;
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7596299)

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Don't repeat the same mistakes as the OP:  provide the best code possible and nothing less.  Your first "option" will fail if there is anything other than exactly 4 values in the list, which is completely valid for paddings/margins.  Simply concatenating the unit to a number turns it into a string (it doesn't matter in this instance because the value isn't used in mathematical operations, but the habit shouldn't be encouraged as it will be confusing to the user down the line when the user *does* need to).

Comment: @cinnamon ... I agree. I suggested the second option that adds the flexibility of passing any number of arguments. And as the OP seemed to want to just print out the values I think just concatenating the unit is not wrong ... but again ... you are right .... it is better to add the units properly ... so I modified that now. But my main point (answering the OP's answer directly) was that you can perform the check with the **`if()`** function.

Answer (score 1):

Your mixin just might be better suited as a function:

```
@function spacing($values: 0) {
    $collector: ();

    @each $v in $values {
        $collector: append($collector, if(unitless($v) and $v != 0, $v * 1px, $v));
    }

    @return $collector;
}

.test{
    margin: spacing(10% 0 5 5);
}
```

Output:

```
.test {
  margin: 10% 0 5px 5px;
}
```

If all you're doing is transforming a single value, functions make it a little more clear that's all that's happening when you come back to read the code later.

Comment: +1 I was thinking this too when answering ... but if the OP wants to also modify/infer the property name or a selector then a mixin is the only way ... this is why I stayed with a mixin in my answer.